# Creating temporary user accounts - Django

Tags: python, django, session

I need to setup temporary User models for each visitors, where the visitors are obviously tied by session data.

I might not be aware of it, but does Django support attaching data to Anonymous users?

---

The only way, I am currently aware of, is to use the session dictionary part of the request object.

---

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with using the session framework? Isn't that what it's for?

Comment: @DanielRoseman if you have a (temporary) user, you can save related data, and just take it and go ahead when the user is getting real/official. I guess this is the reason the OP requests this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have a look at [django-lazysignup](http://github.com/danfairs/django-lazysignup)

> `django-lazysignup` is a package designed to allow users to interact with a site as if they were authenticated users, but without signing up. At any time, they can convert their temporary user account to a real user account.

Comment: @piquadrat wow thanks, that's great! It looks pretty fresh too!

Comment: [django-guest-user](https://django-guest-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) seems to have replaced __django-lazysignup__

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look for sessions. They use cookies, store a unique id into a cookie which is linked to a file on your server containing their data.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/